# TCPDF digital signature not visible in adobe viewer

Tags: php, pdf, digital-signature, tcpdf

I am trying to add Digital signature to existing PDF file using `FPDI` and `TCPDF`, signature is getting added to the PDF file but in Adobe viewer the signature is not visible, a small rectangular block is visible in the PDF but not text in it **(i.e. Signed by John Doe, Date: ............)**

Below is my code,

```
<?php

require_once('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require_once('./tcpdf/tcpdf_import.php');
require_once('./fpdi/fpdi.php');


$pdf   = new FPDI('L', 'mm', 'LETTER'); //FPDI extends TCPDF
$pdf->AddPage();
$pages = $pdf->setSourceFile('pan.pdf');
$page  = $pdf->ImportPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($page, 0, 0);

$certificate = 'file://G:/wamp/www/cert/certificate.crt';

$info = array(
    'Name'        => 'Nishant',
    'Location'    => 'Ahmedabad',
    'Reason'      => 'Testing Signature',
    'ContactInfo' => 'http://www.google.com',
);


$pdf->Text(200, 170, 'Test Content');
$pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'nishant', '', 2, $info);
$pdf->setSignatureAppearance(200, 170, 40, 20);

$pdf->Output('signed.pdf', 'D');
```

Attached is the screenshot of the PDF in adobe viewer
[image]

Also as per the sample given on Adobe website; https://blogs.adobe.com/security/SampleSignedPDFDocument.pdf

A digital signature looks like below screenshot

[image]

If someone can help me out, it will be really appriciated

**Please note**

- I am using self signed certificate, generated using openssl
- I have already checked "View signed version" option in adobe viewer
- I am looking for a opensource answer of digitally signing PDFs

Thanks

Comment: *Also as per the sample given on Adobe website ... a digital signature looks like below screenshot* - **a *sample* is not a *specification*.** PDF signature appearances can contain any static content you want, the Adobe sample shows only one of multiple appearances even Adobe software allows you to create. By the way, the sample signature *merely is an approval signature* while you created a *certification signature*; actually, considering the reason given in the sample, the Adobe sample is a bad example, for an author a certification signature would have been more appropriate.

Comment: @mkl I totally understand, but if you check any of the digitally signed pdf files, it contains some lable like **signed by ABC XYZ, date XXXX-XX-XX XXpm, reason....**, but mine one gets an digital signature but doesnt show any of the information..

Comment: *if you check any of the digitally signed pdf files, it contains some lable like ...* - I have to disagree. I very often come across signed PDFs with no in-document visualization whatsoever; and those with visualizations sometimes only show a symbol (e.g. looking like a seal). That you most often see appearances like the Adobe sample, might be because the signed PDFs you have mostly are signed using Adobe Reader/Acrobat.

Comment: That been said I assume FPDI/TCPDF do allow to choose a visualization more to your liking. Unfortunately I do not know the PHP libraries, so I cannot show.

Comment: @mkl digital signatures can be invisible/visible, invisible signatures does not appear on the pdf, but visible signatures do